# Item Size Error When Updating Item in AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm running tests on the size limit of an item in AWS DynamoDB. In one item the file size is 346kb and I get an error saying I've reached the limit if I try to UPDATE this item with anymore data, which if I understand correctly, the limit is 400kb. So i can understand that I hit the limit here.

But, I have a second item and the file size is 101kb and I get the same error. This one I don't understand.

The difference between the two items, is that the 346kb one has a LIST[ARRAY] that has 36 non-stringified objects (a regular JSON array). 
The item that is 101kb has a LIST[ARRAY] that has 36 stringified objects.

Why/How would I hit the limit with 101kb size item??

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phZBA.png)

Comment: Ok - so the entire JSON document is 101Kb? Or just the fields?

How big are your partitioning and sort keys?

Comment: @Solutegrate ..Can you try to make 101 kb item as regular JSON array same the first one and see if same error occurs there?

Comment: @AdamLuchjenbroers Yes. The whole JSON doc equates to 101kb. pk and sk are only one word strings

Comment: @MukulSharma I should have added that the two items are the exact same key/values except one has a LIST this is stringified and the other has the same LIST un-stringified. Basically I'm doing the stringified to remove white-space and trim it down to make the size smaller, which in fact worked because it's a third of the size, but I'm getting that limit